# RDP 6.1.7600 Bug - Cannot remote connect to clients using NeoWare Thin Clients

Tags: rdp

I've noticed a bug with RDP 6.1.7600. When I try to remote control another user on our Windows Server 2003 machine, I get an error that says "because of a protocol error, this session will be disconnected" and my RDP session is logged out. The error only happens when I try to control a Neoware Thin Clients. Is it because the RDP protocol versions are different?

Comment: You should really edit this to have a meaningful title.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when the client is set to use a visual style of some kind that the server has an issue with.  What happens if you uncheck the "Themes" box on the RDP client config under the Experience tab.

Answer (score 0):

I also have seen this error with network issues server side. Long time ago, but a driver update fixed them.